# Interpreting results of a placebo test

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables

I am using an instrumental variables model to analyze the impact of internet use on hours worked. As part of my analysis, I conduct a placebo test using data from the pre-internet era.

Unfortunately, the results of my placebo test are significant. They indicate that if my instrument Z increases by 1, hours worked (Y) increases by .008.

The results of my main model show that if the instrument Z increases by 1, home internet use (D) goes up by .0005. The second stage shows that if home internet use D goes up by 1, hours worked Y goes up by 16. Thus, if home internet use D goes up by .0005, hours worked Y goes up by .008.

Does this mean that my main-model result could be explained by bias? Alternatively, should I interpret the fact that the placebo test coefficient is close to 0 as evidence that there is minimal bias occuring?

Comment: At lot has changed since the 'pre-internet era'. (I'm old enough to have some recollections from those days.)  So data from that period not be a good benchmark against which to judge current behavior and results.

Comment: Could you tell us more about your instrument? Not knowing what it is, it is difficult to form an opinion about the validity of the instrument, and how it might affect the outcome in the pre-internet era.

Comment: The instrument is a measure of the broadband-friendliness of state broadband deployment legislation from 2002.